# Is there a way to display “calendars in view”, when adding overlay calendar as App Part

Tags: 2013, calendar

I have the following:-

1. 3 calendars (General, internalEvents , ExternalEvents).
2. I added the General calendar as an APP part inside my team site home page.
3. I overlay the internal events and external events, inside the General calendar.
4. I gave each calendar a different colour.
5. Now the general calendar will show all the internal and external events from two other calendars. But the problem is that there is no indication which colour refers to which calendar. Unlike when overlaying a calendar normally (without adding it as a Calendar APP.)